# How to check if in-app purchase already downloaded when restoring in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, rmstore

To restore in-app purchases I use RMStore library.

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^{
    NSLog(@"Transactions restored");
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
}];
```

But this method doesn't check if Apple-hosted content is already downloaded, and download it again. How can I check if an in-app purchase already downloaded or disable automatic content downloading with RMStore library?

Answer (score 0):

It does download Apple-hosted content again. From the [Readme](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore):

> Downloadable content hosted by Apple (SKDownload) will be
>   automatically downloaded when purchasing o restoring a product.

Regarding checking if the content is already downloaded or not, that's up to Apple. I don't know if they support partial downloads or not.

If you're seeing that it doesn't download Apple-hosted content, feel free to submit a [bug](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/issues).